# How do I properly display a chart in html canvas with Chart.js and Angular Framework

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, chart.js

I am following a [tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/live-poll-angular#conclusion) to build a real time polling using angular. However, by the end of the tutorial, I am not able to display the chart like the tutorial does. What am I doing wrong?

I followed the tutorial, used angular, pusher, chart.js as instructed. It worked fine until I reached Data Visualization part, where I need to display the polling result on a 'Doughnut' chart. All I have is a white line which is used to divide different color of the dataset, but the rest of the chart is not displaying.

My app.component.ts

```
voteCount = {
   salah: 0,
   kane: 0,
   eriksen: 0,
   kevin: 0,
};

castVote(player) {
 this.http
  .post(`http://localhost:4000/vote`, { player })
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.vote = res.player;
    this.voted = true;
  });
}

getVoteClasses(player) {
 return {
   elect: this.voted && this.vote === player,
   lost: this.voted && this.vote !== player,
 };
}

chartLabels: string[] = Object.keys(this.voteCount);
chartData: number[] = Object.values(this.voteCount);
chartType = 'doughnut';


ngOnInit() {
  const channel = this.pusher.init();
  channel.bind('vote', ({player}) => {
    this.voteCount[player] += 1;
    this.chartData = Object.values(this.voteCount);
  });
}
```

My app.component.html

```
<div class="chart-box" *ngIf="voted">
  <h2>How others voted</h2>
  <canvas 
    baseChart 
    [data]="chartData"
    [labels]="chartLabels" 
    [chartType]="chartType"
  >
  </canvas>
</div>
```

According to the tutorial, the data visualization should look like this:
[image: Expected]

However, mine looks like this:
[image: Actual]

I changed the background color of the div, so you can see there is a white line below Eriksen just like the tutorial, however, the rest of the data is not shown.

**Edit**: I hard-coded some data and assigned them to `chartLabels`, `chartData` and `chartType`, and now the canvas can visualize them:

```
chartLabels = ['salah', 'kane', 'eriksen', 'kevin'];
chartData = [120, 150, 180, 90];
chartType = 'doughnut';
```

[image: Hardcoded]

So this means

```
chartLabels: string[] = Object.keys(this.voteCount);
chartData: number[] = Object.values(this.voteCount);
chartType = 'doughnut';
```

are not receiving any data. Why is that?

**Edit 2**:

After further experiment, I found that

```
ngOnInit() {
  const channel = this.pusher.init();
  channel.bind('vote', ({player}) => {
    this.voteCount[player] += 1;
    this.chartData = Object.values(this.voteCount);
  });
}
```

`Object.values(this.voteCount)` is not increased so its value stays at 0, so that's why the chart is empty. How do I increase its value each time I click on the player's pic?

Comment: omg, remove the <canvas> element and renamed.

Comment: @GeorgeC. Could you elaborate? Remove <canvas> just made those property displayed as plain text

Comment: the canvas element does not have this inputs 
```
 [data]="chartData"
    [labels]="chartLabels" 
    [chartType]="chartType"
```

Comment: Hi @GeorgeC. I edited my question. I tried hard-code some data into `chartData` and `chartLabels` and they are shown on the chart, so apparently in `app.component.ts`, `Object.keys` and `Object.values` are not returning any data. Why is that?

Comment: How you manage to import the chart.js into angular??

I am trying to import this but I get an import error.

Comment: @GeorgeC. I used `npm install pusher-js chart.js ng2-charts`, then I followed tutorial and imported `import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-Charts';` `imports: [ChartsModule]` in app.module.ts

Comment: ok thanks, I added a stackblitz example